# How can I configure Git to ignore trivial changes (e.g. timestamp) in auto-generated code?

Tags: c, git

I am working with a tool which auto-generates a large amount of C code. The tool generates code for a batch of .c and .h files at each run. For some reason, the tool isn't smart enough to recognize when the files have no substantial changes, so in many cases it simply updates a timestamp in the comments at the top of each file. Otherwise, the file remains unaltered.

When I run `git status` in that scenario, I sometimes see dozens or hundreds of files changed. But as I review the changes to the individual files, most of them have no real changes - just an update to the timestamp. I have to go through each file one-by-one to determine if there are any actual changes to be committed.

Is there a way to configure Git so that it can ignore inconsequential changes such as the timestamp in the header comments? Or how might I otherwise deal with this situation?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: GIT has no way of understanding what a "trival change" is. A file is changed or not. GIT does not understand C (or any other language) it just sees text files whose hashes don't match. So no there is no GIT solution (out the box at least) to do this. You could possibly write a git hook but it seems the solution here is to fix the "tool" not GIT.

Comment: Unfortunately, we do not own the tool, so we are constrained in that respect. Is there a way to create a hook which would look for specific text changes and ignore them?

Comment: Posisbly but I wouldn't imagine it would be easy, read more here https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: There are valid reasons why you would want an auto-generated source file in your git repository, but are you sure you want to?

Comment: Yes, in our case, we do need to track the auto-generated files, since there is a good deal of configuration that is done to them to make them work in our project.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I discovered a way to address the problem of trivial changes using [Beyond Compare](https://www.scootersoftware.com/). I will describe the process as it pertains to ignoring timestamp updates in auto-generated C files, but it can be easily adapted to other situations and languages:

1. Configure Beyond Compare as the Git difftool. See [here](https://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs_osx) for specific details about how to do this.
2. (Optional but helpful) Add a Git alias for the `git difftool --dir-diff --no-symlinks` command (for example, `dtd`).
3. Make some changes (e.g. auto-generate your files), and run `git dtd` to do a directory diff. Beyond Compare will open and show you a before/after Folder Comparison of your changes.
4. Open a Text Compare session window for one of your changed files. Open the **Tools** menu and select **File Formats**.
5. Open the **Grammar** tab, delete the "Comments" grammar element.
6. Add a new grammar element and give it a meaningful name such as "Generation Time Comment".
7. For Category, select the "Delimited" grammar element. In the "Text from" box, enter the text you would like to ignore. For example, if the timestamp in your auto-generated code starts with the string `* Generation Time:`, enter it into the "Text from" box. Check the "Stop at end of line" checkbox.
8. Click the "Save" button and go back to your Text Compare session window.
9. Open the **Session** menu and select **Session Settings**. Open the **Importance** tab.
10. Look for your new grammar element (e.g. "Generation Time Comment") and uncheck it. This will tell Beyond Compare to treat it as an unimportant change.
11. Open the **Comparison** tab, select **Rule-Based Comparison**.
12. Change the dropdown at the bottom of the dialog to **Update session defaults**.
13. Close Beyond Compare, and then reopen it again by running the `git dtd` command.
14. All of the files in the Folder Compare session which contain nothing but an update to the timestamp will be shown with unimportant differences. If you want to completely hide files with unimportant differences, toggle off **Ignore Unimportant Differences** in the **View** menu.

Reference: https://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_unimportantv3

Comment: This might work with an external tool (Beyond Compare), but the question asked about generic Git, and the answer to be broadly useful should not depend on a particular proprietary software.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to configure Git so that it can ignore inconsequential changes such as the timestamp in the header comments? Or how might I otherwise deal with this situation?

Yes; this is the purpose of a *filter*.

You might be familiar with git's notion of "clean" and "smudge" filters already, that's how it handles line ending conversion.  When you are on a Windows computer and have Windows-style line endings in your working directory, you might set a `.gitattribute` like `* text=auto` indicating that you want files checked into the repository with "normalized" Unix-style line endings.  In this case, the files will have the "clean" filter applied to convert `\r\n` line endings to `\n` style line endings.  Similarly, the files will be "smudged" on checkout to convert from `\n` to `\r\n` on-disk.

You can create your own clean and smudge filters to remove (or add) data when translating between the working directory and the repository.  For these files you can add an attribute:

```
*.c filter=autogen
```

And then you can configure your autogen filter, with commands to run in the "clean" (into the repository) and "smudge" (into the working directory) directions.

```
git config --global filter.autogen.clean remove_metadata
git config --global filter.autogen.smudge cat
```

(Using cat is a "noop" as far as filters are concerned).

The [Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes) has more detailed examples of creating your own filters.

Answer (score 0):

I have a file *xxx.pro.user* with timestamp, and want git to ignore the time change:

```
<!-- Written by QtCreator 9.0.1, 2023-06-29T10:47:99. -->
....
```

(1) Place the filter to *.git/config* file at the root of the repository (after things like [branch "master"] ...):

```
...
[filter "ignore_ts"]
    clean = sed '/Written by QtCreator/d'
    smudge = cat
```

(2) In the directory where *xxx.pro.user* is, add file *.gitattributes* that applies the filter to the target file:

```
xxx.pro.user filter=ignore_ts
```

(3) Verify the filter:

```
$ git check-attr --all xxx.pro.user
xxx.pro.user: filter: ignore_ts
```

Also, test your filter as commands directly to see the effect as expected:

```
$ cat xxx.pro.user | sed '/Written by QtCreator/d' > testfile
$ diff xxx.pro.user testfile
< <!-- Written by ...-->
```

(4) Make changes to the timestamp of *xxx.pro.user*, and run *git status*.
Note: If already modified, use *git restore*, or *git add* + *git commit*. Then subsequent modifications of the timestamp will be ignored.

() Bonus, you may add a *diff* filter to *.git/config*

```
[diff "ignore_ts_diff"]
    textconv = sed '/Written by QtCreator/d'
```

activate on different target files in *.gitattributes*:

```
xxx.pro.user filter=ignore_ts diff=ignore_ts_diff
xxx.pro.user2 filter=ignore_ts diff=ignore_ts_diff
```

Now, *git diff xxx.pro.user2* will ignore the timestamp difference.